# Invalid character error when parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to parse JSON data from an external json file (an Array). But noting is being returned. I'm getting an error (F12) `Invalid character`. What might be the issue here? How can I fix this?

```
var myAr;

$.ajax({url: 'test.json'}).done(function(d) {
  myAr = JSON.parse(d); // Invalid character
});
```

external file:

```
[ [ "Parrot", "Green"], [ "Swan", "White"] ]
```

Comment: Your JSON should use a hash instead of an array of arrays.

Comment: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/132927/json-arrays-within-an-array here is example how to parse array of arrays in JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you retrieve JSON via AJAX using jQuery it will automatically deserialise it for you. Calling `JSON.parse()` again on the resulting object will cause the error as you've seen. In your code `d` is already an object containing all the properties returned from the request, ready for you to use:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'test.json' }).done(function(d) {
    console.log(d); // shows the returned object
});
```